# How to save MySQL count() row into an PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, count

Hello i want to save one row which comes out of a MySQL database with "count('row1'') AS sum" but inside my array i only got empty fields!

Database query:

```
"SELECT id, value, COUNT('value') AS sum FROM answer_user GROUP BY id,value"
```

php code:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo"<b>{$data['id']}#{$data['value']}#{$data['sum']}#<br>";
}
```

but $data[sum] is just empty and no numbers are inside.

And a small but minor annoiance is that i can't oder by id descending and value ascending in my query, like value is descending with my query phpMyAdmin says:

```
   id value     sum
    1   0   1
    1   1   3
    1   2   1
    1   6   1
    2   2   4
    2   5   1
    2   6   1
    3   2   1
    3   3   4
    3   6   1
```

my main aim would be to store it in one two dimensional array like $data[id][value]="[sum]"

that if i do echo"$data[1][1]"; the result should be plain 3

var_dump($data)
array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["value"]=> string(1) "0" ["sum"]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["value"]=> string(1) "1" ["sum"]=> string(1) "3" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["value"]=> string(1) "2" ["sum"]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["value"]=> string(1) "6" ["sum"]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["value"]=> string(1) "2" ["sum"]=> string(1) "4" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["value"]=> string(1) "5" ["sum"]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["value"]=> string(1) "6" ["sum"]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["value"]=> string(1) "2" ["sum"]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["value"]=> string(1) "3" ["sum"]=> string(1) "4" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["value"]=> string(1) "6" ["sum"]=> string(1) "1" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["value"]=> string(1) "2" ["sum"]=> string(1) "2" } array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["value"]=> string(1) "4" ["sum"]=> string(1) "4" }

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($data);` and I would recommend you to enclose the array indeces in qoutes.

Comment: why would you want all the columns stored in the keys of a multidimensional array? that means you would need all the answers first, and no response data

Comment: Do you want to get the sum of values of the field "value"?

Comment: the field values only reflects my database values like school notes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your query is that you are usign count('value') as sum. Mysql is getting value as string you should use it like this.

```
SELECT id, value, COUNT(value) AS sum FROM answer_user GROUP BY id,value
```

And add order by

```
SELECT id, value, COUNT(value) AS sum FROM answer_user GROUP BY id,value order by id asc , value asc
```

Its bringing perfect result. The order by will first sort with id then against each idwith value. And the result you have shown here doesn't display there is any 0 returned in sum.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
while($data= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$data['id']][$data['value']] = $data['sum'];
}
```

Comment: yours is close to my solution: $array[$data['id']][$data['value']] = $data['sum'];
should give me an array with $array[1][1]= 3 but it does not??

Comment: that's weird, what do you get? which variable makes an error?

Answer (score -2):

try putting { & } as well as ' around the keys around the arrays like in the edit